# How to use match inside map function in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm a beginner to Mongodb, I want to execute the following query to find the total number of assignments for each employee with assignment progress "working".

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "assignment",
      "localField": "empno",
      "foreignField": "emp_no",
      "as": "assignments"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      points: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$assignments",
            in: { $match:{$Sthis.progress:"Working"}}
          }
        }
      },
      empno: 1
    }
  }
])
```

When I execute this query I get the error "Invalid $project:: caused by:: Unrecognized expression '$match'". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add filter to input of map and set condition in filter

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "assignment",
      "localField": "empno",
      "foreignField": "emp_no",
      "as": "assignments"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      points: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input:{"$filter":
            { "input": "$assignments", "as": "z", "cond": {$eq:["$$z.progress","Working"]} } },
            as :"s",
            in: "$$s"
          }
        }
      },
      empno: 1
    }
  
    
  }
])
```

Comment: im getting this error "Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'." in mogodbcompass.

Comment: I update my asnwer , pls try again

Comment: Thank you I tried again the query is working but my output for points seems to be 0, although there are is " progress: Working " in the database. Can you explain wait happened in the input field? Does it work in counting String values?

Comment: The issue is with the sum function I guess with out it filters properly, any solution for that? since I want to get the total. Is there a way to count the returning array of elements for points?

Comment: Output I get with sum:

{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dede"),
  empno: 10,
  points: 0 }
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dedf"),
  empno: 11,
  points: 0 }
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dee0"),
  empno: 12,
  points: 0 }

Comment: Output I get without sum:
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dede"),
  empno: 10,
  points: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee1"),
       assid: 'Assignment1',
       empno: 10,
       progress: 'Working' },
     { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee4"),
       assid: 'Assignment3',
       empno: 10,
       progress: 'Working' } ] }
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dedf"),
  empno: 11,
  points: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee2"),
       assid: 'Assignment1',
       empno: 11,
       progress: 'Working' } ] }

Comment: could you provide sample data after lookup to fix issue ?

Comment: lookup I get this : 
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dede"),
  empno: 10,
  name: 'John',
  assignments: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee1"),
       assid: 'Assignment1',
       empno: 10,
       progress: 'Working' },
     { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee4"),
       assid: 'Assignment3',
       empno: 10,
       progress: 'Working' } ] }
{ _id: ObjectId("61406d010da080a2dad0dedf"),
  empno: 11,
  name: 'Peter',
  assignments: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61406d8b0da080a2dad0dee2"),
       assid: 'Assignment1',
       empno: 11,    progress: 'Working' },